# Excel columns comparison using python code

Tags: python, excel, data-comparison

I am working with excel for comparing three columns: my idea is to compare two columns of data with a third column as a array like each value in the 3rd column should be compared with every row of the first and second column and want to extract only those rows where the first and second column's data is present in the third column I used this python command

```
if([x in x,y for datafile] == [x in x for file) and [y in x,y for datafile] == [x in x for file]): 
    print x,y
else:
    print none
```

this gave me an error as syntax error

I have converted my first two columns into a tuple using the `zip` function the x,y corresponds to the values in the tuple

```
Col_1 ||  Col_2    ||   file
Abc   |    Abk     |    cnl
Nck   |    Nck     |    Abk
xkl   |    cnl     |    Abc  
mzn   |    mzn     |
```

this I have combined as datafile `((Abc,Abk),(Nck,Nck),(xkl,cnl),(mzn,mzn))`

Note: my column 3 has smaller values than col 1&2. I have over 100k values to compare

I want a working python program for this  query

```
if [x for x,y in mydata if x == genelist and
y for x,y in mydata if y == genelist]:
    print (x,y)
else:
```

can someone correct the syntax error in the above code here

```
mydata('gene1,genea','gene2,geneb''gene3,genec') and genelist ('genea','geneb','genec')
```

when I use the code without if statement it prints me "[]" I don't know what's wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [pandas.Series.isin](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to filter it:

For your excel data (`eg:comparison.xlsx`) :

[image]

Use:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('comparison.xlsx')
result = df[df['finaldata1'].isin(list(df['check'])) & df['finaldata2'].isin(list(df['check']))]
result
```

it will give you:

```
    finaldata1  finaldata2  check
0   Abc         Abk         cnl
```

as `Abc` and `Abk` is in column `file`.

**Update:** Write result to excel file:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter

writer = ExcelWriter('PythonExport.xlsx')
result.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

The result will be write into excel file `PythonExport.xlsx`:

[image]

Comment: Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:28:03) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import xlrd
>>> df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx')
>>> result = df[df['finaldata'].isin(list[df['check']])]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    result = df[df['finaldata'].isin(list[df['check']])]
TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: Your result is not correct, should be `result = df[df['finaldata'].isin(list(df['check']))]` **not** `result = df[df['finaldata'].isin(list[df['check']])]`, change to `()` after `list` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [finaldata, check]
Index: []

Comment: are you sure there is data in your `df` ? it seems that your `df` is empty

Comment: data is present anyways the program allows comparison with one column but i wanna compare two columns of data with an array/list of data

Comment: thank you so much that worked great I have got the expected output can you help me to write the results onto an excel file from python

Comment: If it is solution, pls mark it as an accept answer. I will update it to let you know how to write result to excel file.

Comment: I have clicked the up arrow to vote should I do something else to accept ?

Comment: Up vote is for the answer is useful, accept is for you to accept it to a right answer for your question.

Comment: @LakshmiKrishnaKumaar you haven't mark it as accept answer, please mark it if the answer help you, and it can be closed also, Thanks.

Comment: I cant find out how to accept the answer I have upvoted which the blog is accepting how should I accept sorry this is the first question I post herer

Comment: @LakshmiKrishnaKumaar please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done it sorry for the trouble

Comment: Cheers, hope you will enjoy StackOverFlow

Comment: for the above mentioned question of mine I found a solution in awk     awk '{a[$1]; next} $1 in a && '